# How to maintain image aspect ratio in modal using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

I have an image gallery in my modal, which is styled using flexbox. The problem is that some pictures which are too large horizontally flow over and make the flexbox stretch, so the item next to it is messed up, eventhough the flex weights are set in css.

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade" style="display: block;">
         <div class="numbertext">1 / 16</div>
              <img src="./img/normal/image.jpg" class="galimg" style="height: 331px;">
         <div class="text">Image description</div>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

I want each image to maintain its aspect ratio. Some are landscape, some are portrait. So I thought I'd try the following:

```
var maxHeight = $('#modal-gallery').height()-39; // need 39px for the gallery navigation. 
var maxWidth = $('#modal-gallery').width();
var ratio = maxHeight/maxWidth;
$('.galimg').each(function(i){  
    if ($(this).height()/$(this).width() > ratio){
        $(this).width(maxWidth);
    } else {
        $(this).height(maxHeight);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#modal-gallery { // this is the div surrounding the gallery
    flex: 6;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I know the problem is probably somewhere in my JS, as I tried logging the width and height and often got 0. The html is generated dynamically through JS. I tried adding an onImgLoad function, but didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do a js thing. Just fix your css. Add some styles and HTML elements. The following is the most common way to show different size images in many websites (Please also expand the snippet to see how it behaves).

```css
#modal-gallery { // this is the div surrounding the gallery
    flex: 6;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
.mySlides{
    display:block
}
.slide-image{
  display:inline-block;
  width:220px; 
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.img-container{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
}
.img-container .img{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.img-container img{
  max-height:200px;
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="slide-image">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 16</div>
          <div class="img-container">
            <div class="img">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider1.jpg" class="galimg" />
            </div>
          </div>                
          <div class="text">Image description</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-image">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 16</div>
          <div class="img-container">
            <div class="img">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" class="galimg" />
            </div>
          </div>                
          <div class="text">Image description</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-image">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 16</div>
          <div class="img-container">
            <div class="img">
              <img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg" class="galimg" />
            </div>
          </div>                
          <div class="text">Image description</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-image">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 16</div>
          <div class="img-container">
            <div class="img">
              <img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg" class="galimg" />
            </div>
          </div>                
          <div class="text">Image description</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-image">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 16</div>
          <div class="img-container">
            <div class="img">
              <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider1.jpg" class="galimg" />
            </div>
          </div>                
          <div class="text">Image description</div>
      </div>
       <div class="slide-image">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 16</div>
          <div class="img-container">
            <div class="img">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" class="galimg" />
            </div>
          </div>                
          <div class="text">Image description</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```